# how to use already-downloaded Miktex 2.8 packages?

Tags: miktex, texmaker

After a lot of bother with setting up a Miktex-Texmaker-Adobe arrangement, I've now done a basic install of non-portable Miktex 2.8, which is working fine. But given the slowness of my internet connection, I'd like to be able to use a large number of packages I already downloaded as part of a previous install, rather than download packages on the fly. I know I'm supposed to put miktex-zzdb1-2.8 and miktex-zzdb1-2.9 somewhere, but where exactly? and in what order do I need to refresh FNDB from mo.exe, run texhash, alter the Texmaker 3.3.4 config, and so on? The OS is Win 7 Pro, and the main Miktex directory is "C:\Program Files (x86)\ MiKTeX 2.8". Thanks in advance for any help with this!

Comment: Which is the reason to install MiKTeX 2.8, when MiKTeX 2.9 exists? Updating would BTW work the same way, as already described by Ulrike (and me, cf. [Relocate MiKTeX 2.9?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56322/9237)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit unclear what you mean by packages. If you downloaded with the setup wizard  lzma, cab etc files which are on ctan in miktex/tm/packages/ to some folder you should be able to use this folder as "local repository" with the package manager.

If you installed the packages in a older miktex in a texmf then you should use `mpm --import-all` to import them see http://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/mpm.html.