# Changing the location of auto-installed packages in MiKTeX

Tags: installing, miktex

This is a software question, specific to MiKTeX: I have automatic downloading of packages enabled, so that if I try to use a style that's not in the existing directory trees, it is downloaded from CTAN and installed. The problem is that MiKTeX installs it under `%APPDATA%` (at `C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Application Data\MiKTeX\2.9`), which bloats my roaming profile. Is there a way to change this destination?

I already have another root for styles I install myself, but I can't get MiKTeX to use it for auto-installed packages. In the Roots list in MiKTeX Settings (`mo.exe`), the `%APPDATA%` folder has the tag "UserInstall". It won't let me edit or delete its path, or tag another root "UserInstall".  Is there a way to do this, or am I stuck with rearranging the downloaded packages by hand afterwards?

Comment: I don't think that you can change UserInstall in a running miktex but it is possible to set it at installation time: http://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/setupwiz.html

Comment: I'm guessing this setting can probably be changed by editing the registry... but it was easy enough to re-install.

Comment: Additional tip for a re-installation: [Relocate MiKTeX 2.9?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56172/relocate-miktex-2-9/56322#56322).

Comment: You could use Ulrike’s and my information and provide a self answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Ulrike explained in the comments above, it seems that MikTeX allows the `UserInstall` directory to be configured only during installation. So, it's easiest to just re-install it, calling the installer from the commandline with suitable options. The full set of commandline options for the installer is [documented here.](http://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/setupwiz.html)

I first removed the existing MikTeX by running the uninstaller from the Start menu. I then opened a command prompt (this is on Windows), switched to the directory containing the downloaded installer, and ran the following:

```
C:\...> basic-miktex-***.exe --shared --user-install="C:\Path\to\my\root"
```

I used `--shared` since it's being installed for all users, but I was asked again during the set-up dialog anyway. There are also options `--user-config` and `--user-data` (I don't mind leaving those in the default location).

I am just setting up a new computer, so this was a no-brainer. I follow [best practices](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69487/12092) and keep all style files that are *not* managed by MikTeX in a separate texmf hierarchy, so there was no need to salvage anything before uninstalling. But if you have been dropping your non-CTAN styles into the MikTeX texmf tree (definitely not a good idea), or have a huge texmf tree and a slow internet connection, or use your computer off-line a lot and don't want to be surprised by missing packages, you can follow [this procedure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56172/relocate-miktex-2-9/56322#56322), which lets you use your old `texmf` tree as the data source for the new installation (thanks @Speravir for the pointer).

Answer (score 1):

As opposed to what the accepted answer says, it not "easier" to reinstall. One can make a simple edit in the registry: the install dir for packages is set on 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MiKTeX.org\MiKTeX\2.9\Core\UserInstall`

Comment: Good information, thanks! This would definitely be the way to go for an older installation (for which wiping and recreating would trigger unnecessary downloads, and possibly incompatibilities). For completeness: The registry is edited by running `regedit` from the CMD prompt, right?

Comment: Yes, with an administrator account.

Comment: *Riight,* administrator account. Forgot about all that. Not sure what happens on a roaming profile in a University environment (my use case), where I have limited admin rights. But fortunately, I don't personally need to try this anymore. :-)

Comment: There's no UserInstall in the Registry on my PC (Win 10, MiKTeX 2.9)

Comment: UserInstall might not be present in HKEY_CURRENT_USER, but might be in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Comment: UserInstall in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE cannot (and should not) be edited by non-privileged users of shared workstations.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by executing the installer from cmd prompt as portable installation:

```
basic-miktex-21.12-x64.exe --private --auto-install=yes --paper-size=A4 --portable=<destination-dir>
```

and add the `<destination-dir>\install\miktex\bin\x64` folder manually to HKCU:\Environment\Path

Comment: So you just install a local "portable" Miktex, and of course packages are installed there too. That's good when it's sufficient, but it's not much help in a setup where Miktex is already installed on university computers, and I sit on a different computer every time.