# error "latexdiff: The Perl Script could not be found."

Tags: miktex, scripts, latexdiff, perl

I have `MikTeX 2.9` installation and `Strawberry Perl 5.10.1.5.`

All the `latexdiff`, `latexdiff-fast`, `latexidff-so` paths seem to be present in the `scripts.ini` file and their `.exe` files in the `miktex/bin/x64`.

Somehow when I try to run `latexdiff` command in the directory where the two versions of `.tex` files are present, I get this error

```
latexdiff: The Perl script could not be found.

latexdiff: Data: scripts/latexdiff/perl/latexdiff.pl
```

When I run the command, a pop-up window asks for installation of `latexdiff.pl` and I press ok, but it ends up in the error shown above. I followed some posts with similar problem, but couldn't find a solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in MiKTeX: With the call of `latexdiff` you actually make a call of `latexdiff.exe`, what is a wrapper. In this wrapper the path shown in th error message seem s to be hardcoded, but it is empty on my machine. So file a bug in the [MiKTeX Bugs Tracker](http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/). BTW there were recently also problems with other perl based scripts in MiKTeX.

Comment: I think, it is not really related, but let me point you to [latexdiff problem in MikTex 2.8 after update: “Perl script not found”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95699/latexdiff-problem-in-miktex-2-8-after-update-perl-script-not-found).

Comment: @Speravir I came across this post before I posted mine, but the post didn't really suggest a solution. I'll try to file a bug with the MiKTeX Bugs Tracker.

Comment: @Speravir MiKTeX Bugs Tracker doesn't allow to me file the bug. I created an account in SourceForge and tried creating a ticket, but it says 'We are sorry your request could not be processed' and doesn't give any further information.

Answer (score 2):

I've just faced this exact problem with `latexdiff`.

Follow the solution found here for a different package,

http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=14677

but also rename the `latexdiff` perl files to also have a `.pl` extension.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Please consider to include more details, so that your answer becomes self-contained.

Comment: I followed this approach (made a folder perl in scripts/latexdiff, moved all files there; added .pl to all of them and refresh FNDB) and I still get the error. Did I miss something?

Comment: I moved latexdiff.pl to my working folder and invoked perl latexdiff.pl old.tex new.tex > diff.tex but I would like to use it normally from miktex.

Comment: Could you explain what you actually did step by step? I tried simply making a `/perl` folder in `MiKTeX 2.9/scripts/latexdiff` and giving everything a `.pl` extension and the same error still occurs.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe not what you want but have you tried installing **Cygwin**, **Perl** and `latexdiff` there? I think installing TeXLive is also an option but installing 2Gb software just to have access to a script might be too much. I do understand how `latexdiff` can be important. Several journals where I was submitting asked me for the difference between submitted and reviewed versions of papers.