# Problem regarding Latexdiff, Perl and MikTex 2.9 on Win7

Tags: miktex, latexdiff, perl, cygwin

I try to implement [this interesting solution for latexdiff and multiple files](https://eothred.wordpress.com/2010/11/07/latexdiff-and-git/). There are other questions regarding missing perl scripts but I cannot relate them or their solutions to my problem ([i.e. perl script not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95699/latexdiff-problem-in-miktex-2-8-after-update-perl-script-not-found))(perhaps because I am a beginner). However using...

- Win7 (64-bit)
- GitHub (Sourcetree, Git version 1.8.0msysgit.0)
- MikTex 2.9
- ActivePerl version 5.16.2.1602
- cygwin

I receive the following error:

[image: Error]

I am a beginner but already checked that Algorithm-diff is installed:

`C:\progs\perl\site\lib\Algorithm`

[image: algorithm-diff (perl) is installed]

Can someone help? I cannot find the path `/usr/lib/perl5...`. Latexdiff is installed  in `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff`. Perl is installed in `C:\progs\perl`but the folder `lib\perl5`is not there.

**Update:**

Tried to implement [this solution for How to change @INC to find Perl modules in non-standard locations](https://web.archive.org/web/20140413214836/http://perlmaven.com/how-to-change-inc-to-find-perl-modules-in-non-standard-locations) by adding `C:\progs\perl\site\lib` to the new Environment (User) Variables PERL5LIB and PERLLIB. It did work.

Comment: By any chance are they related ? [Problem executing script for latexdiff](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104450/15717).

Comment: I also had this issue and found that by using a theportable version of perl from http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html, placing this in `C:\tmp\perl` running `C:\tmp\perl\portableshell.bat` and then running `latexdiff` from there worked fine

Comment: for those who end up here, you need to make sure you are adding the `latexdiff` to the right version of Perl. If you are on Windows use `where perl` and on Linux/macOS use `which perl`. If you have multiple versions of perl then you might face some issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions answered, see update above: "adding C:\progs\perl\site\lib to the new Environment (User) Variables PERL5LIB and PERLLIB."

Comment: Put your answer in the answer, not the question.