# Can't locate Algorithm/Diff.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Algorithm::Diff module)

Tags: miktex, latexdiff, perl

I'm having the same problem as described in the closed question "https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104350/problem-regarding-latexdiff-perl-and-miktex-2-9-on-win7".

Following the solution does not work in my case. However, the error message now includes the path I added (see below).

I've installed latexdiff via MikTeX 2.9 console on Win10. Originally tried with ActivePerl, then uninstalled and installed Strawberry Perl. Issue persists.

```
$ latexdiff
Can't locate Algorithm/Diff.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Algorithm::Diff module) (@INC contains: C \Strawberry\perl\site\lib /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/share/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl /usr/share/perl5/core_perl) at C:\Users\pea77\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts/latexdiff\latexdiff line 193.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Users\pea77\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts/latexdiff\latexdiff line 193.
```

Answer (score 6):

Install the `Algorithm::Diff` package from Perl's CPAN package repository.  You can do this by running the following command.

```
perl -MCPAN -e "install Algorithm::Diff"
```

Comment: I ran it and got  C:\Strawberry\perl\bin>perl -MCPAN -e "install Algorithm::Diff"
Database was generated on Mon, 11 Apr 2022 04:59:42 GMT
Algorithm::Diff is up to date (1.201)  

However I still get the error Can't locate Algorithm/Diff.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Algorithm::Diff module)   when using latexdiff

Comment: You shouldn't need to navigate to `C:\Strawberry\perl\bin` in order to run the command. If this is the case, it seems that your path is misconfigured, and the version of Perl used by *latexdiff* is different from the one you're using to install the package. For example, in my installation *latexdiff* probably pulls Perl from `AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/tlpkg/tlperl/bin/perl.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

Installing from CPAN is the correct solution, but it fails with a cryptic error if you are using the Perl from MSYS2 under Windows. In that case install it with `pacman`:

```
pacman -S perl-Algorithm-Diff
```

Comment: Actually failed with the same error message in MSYS2, but your answer works. Thanks a lot.