# Compilation of LaTex in Windows? With TeXnicCenter or other software?

Tags: installing, compiling, miktex, windows, texniccenter

I am forced to use Windows -machine during certain classes, software provided by this party [here](https://into.aalto.fi/display/enit/Homepage). I have earlier compiled things through SSH but now trying to use Tex -softwares built for Windows working such as TeXnicCenter and some compiler but it apparently misses the compiler. I am now trying to install the MikTex -LaTex-compiler for Windows but `"initexmf.exe: Windows API error 5: Access is denied."` so my system -admistrators apparently not allowing me to compile LaTex in Windows.

> 1. So how can I get the PDF -document out of this GUI -tool?
> 2. When I build, the "build output" is empty. Why?

[image]

**Perhaps related**

> 1. Perhaps useful for the MikTex -error: [Windows API error 5: "Access is denied" when trying to compile TikZ picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51799/windows-api-error-5-access-is-denied-when-trying-to-compile-tikz-picture) and [here](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=17499).

Comment: What TeXing engine did you install?

Comment: Maybe you can at least check what TeXnicCenter is looking for (somewhere in the option panel), and check if that software is available on your machine, then.

Comment: `Build > Define output profiles...` and then check the default profile

Comment: @T.Verron the problem is the lack of default profile, there is no profile! Currently trying to install MikTex -LaTex-compiler for windows [here](http://miktex.org/).

Comment: @hhh As this is a 'managed' system, I'd say you need to talk to whoever is in charge. The general case of using TeXniccenter does work with a correctly-installed TeX system, so this is something 'local'.

Comment: Miktex provides a [portable version](http://miktex.org/portable) that does not require any software to be installed, that should help you getting a working TeX version without administrative rights on the machine at hand.

Comment: If you are using Adobe Reader DC, check this link: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250472/texniccenter-adobe-reader-dc

Answer (score 5):

### Requirements

The preliminary steps can be summarized as follows:

Note that for each installation, just accept the default settings.

1. Install either TeX Live 2012 or MikTeX (the latest version).
2. Install Adobe Reader.
3. Install TeXnicCenter (RC1 is the stable one).

### Configurations

Now configure the installed TeXnicCenter as follows:

1. Run the TeXnicCenter, you will be prompted to specify the path to TeX binary as follows.

   [image]
2. Pressing the `Next` button, you will be prompted to find the TeX binary path. Press the `Browse` button to locate the path.

   [image]

   For TeX Live the path is as follows,

   [image]

   If you installed MikTeX then the path will be different, please locate it by yourself.
3. Pressing the `Next` button will bring up the following window, just accept the default.

   [image]
4. Pressing the `Next` button again will bring up the following window, just click the `Finish` button.

   [image]

### Override Output Profiles

If you installed Adobe Reader 10 (X in roman) then you need to modify the output profiles. Press `Alt+F7` to bring up the `Profiles` window, choose an item to modify (for example `LaTeX => PDF`), select `Viewer` tab. Your edit should  look as follows,

[image]

### Make a try

[image]

Create a new blank document by pressing the white icon right below the `File` menu (I enclosed it with a red rectangle). Type the following dummy text, save it, make sure you choose `LaTeX => PDF` item (I enclosed it with a red rectangle), then press `CTRL+SHIFT+F5`.

And congratulation, you will get a PDF output as follows:

[image]

Comment: +1 thank you, this may be useful to someone, I need to wait for my sysadmin now unless some way to compile LaTex without physically installing it, perhaps some virtualized version of LaTex -compiler for windows?

Comment: Usually you can install texlive locally.