# TeXnicCenter & Adobe Reader DC

Tags: pdf, texniccenter, adobe

How to configure TeXnicCenter to work with Adobe Reader DC? When I building and view current file .tex the following error "Can not execute the command" shows up and the PDF is not generated.

[image: error TeXnicCenter]

If there are any related post, could help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43864/texniccenter-adobe-acrobat-10

Comment: My impression is that http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43864/texniccenter-adobe-acrobat-10 does not help for Adobe Reader DC. I read it, but I still have the same problem as asked.

Comment: Indeed, this post does not help for Adobe Reader DC. My solution was to download another version of adobe reader, we can choose this link: http://get.adobe.com/uk/reader/otherversions/. The version XI worked well in TexNicCenter.

Comment: Does your output open directly in the Adobe reader now? Or does the Adobe reader open after compiling?

Comment: I guess the 2019 version is out.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The newest trailing number for 2024 update is either `acroviewA24` or `acroviewR24`.

The screenshots below still uses the old trailing number and it no longer works.

---

This can be solved by using proper settings in TeXnicCenter:

1. Go to menu: "Build"-> "Define Output Profiles."
2. Choose profile "LateX to PDF".
3. Switch to "Viewer" tab
4. Set-up parameters:

"Executable path" should be something like (check, where have you installed Adobe Reader):

```
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe
```

or if you have the 32-bit version:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe
```

**Note**: If you install the 32-bit version on Windows 64-bit, the next automatic update of Adobe Acrobat may change it from 32-bit to 64-bit.

Parameters: "Command", "Server" and "Topic" appears three-times on settings page - be sure to change ALL three appearences correctly.

- "Server" parameter takes the form

  ```
   acroview<Letter><YY>
  ```

  Where `<YY>` should be the last two digits of the year in the Adobe
  Acrobat version (which can be found under `Help -> About Adobe Arobat Reader` in Adobe Reader), for version `2023.x.x` this is `23`, and `<Letter>`
  is a single letter which is `R` for the **32-bit** version and `A`
  for the **64-bit** version.

  So for the 64-bit version 2022.001.20085 it would be:

  ```
   acroviewA22
  ```

  For the 32-bit version 2021.007.20099 it would be:

  ```
   acroviewR21
  ```
- "Topic" parameter should be always:

  ```
   control
  ```
- "Command" parameter should be twice:

  ```
   [DocOpen("%bm.pdf")][FileOpen("%bm.pdf")]
  ```

  Last instance of "Command" parameter (in "close document..."
  section) should be:

  ```
   [DocClose("%bm.pdf")]
  ```

After setting everything, confirm "Profiles" dialog and it is done.

Or you can just check following examples

- Adobe Acrobat Reader DC **64-bit** version **2022.001.20085**:

[image]

- Adobe Acrobat Reader DC **32-bit** version **2022.001.20085**:

[image]

Comment: That little `acroviewR15` did the trick for me. Great answer!

Comment: The acroviewR15 part solved it for me too. Thank you!

Comment: additionally in Acrobat you might need to change `Edit` -> `Preferences` -> `Security(Enhanced)`: uncheck `Enable Protected Mode at startup`

Comment: With the April 2017 update to Acrobat Reader DC, [the server parameter has to be `acroviewR17`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364613/1236).

Comment: **With the newest update** `2018.009.20044` and beyond, please change all "Server" parameter from `acroviewR17` to `acroviewR18`.  Check your Adobe version using `Help > About Adobe Acrobat Reader DC`.

Comment: For Acrobat Pro DC, use `acroviewA18`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. My Acrobat Reader DC version is 2018.011.20038.

Comment: to figure out which version to use, you can look in the registry under: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\acrobat\shell\open\ddeexec\application`

Comment: With the newest update 2019 and beyond, if your using Reader please change all "Server" parameter from acroviewR18 to acroviewR19. Check your Adobe version using Help > About Adobe Acrobat Reader DC. For those with Editor versions (3D standard **Pro DC** etc.) its now AcroviewA19

Comment: The "acroviewR18" needs updating to "acroviewR19". I had this error until I tried the latter as above.

Comment: now it's acroviewR20

Comment: now:  acroviewR21

Comment: I've abandoned Adobe Reader and switched to Sumatra, mainly because of the locking issue with Reader but partly for this too.

Comment: After the newest update to version 2021.007.20099 (sic) ,,acroviewR21'' does not work anymore: I tried with acroviewA21 (as suggested in the newest update of the answer ) but still the same error pops out. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: @truebaran: change `acrord32.exe` to `acrobat.exe`.

Comment: as of today, 'acroviewA23' works for me. I am using the Reader version, 64-bit, in Windows

Answer (score 28):

With the (silent) April 2017 update to Acrobat Reader DC to version 2017.009.20044, the [parameters in Jiří's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255615/1236) don't work anymore. TeXnicCenter just stops responding when trying to view the output with <kbd>F5</kbd>.

To solve the problem, simply replace the server parameter from `acroviewR15` to `acroviewR17` like below.

The dialog can be accessed with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>. Read more about the [new Acrobat Reader version number here](https://blogs.adobe.com/deployment/2017/03/acrobats-getting-a-new-version-number-reader-too.html).

[image]

Comment: I've edited his answer, I think that's more useful for other people than another answer with less votes.

Answer (score 7):

*To complement the answers by [Jiří Chmelík](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255615/109294) and [Frank Seifert](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364613/109294).*

---

**Update:** In October 2018, Adobe Acrobat Reader DC has been updated to [2019.008.20071](https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/acrobat/apsb18-30.html). `acroviewR19` should be used instead, if you have this or a newer version.

---

In November 2017, Adobe Acrobat Reader DC has been updated to [2018.009.20044](https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/acrobat/apsb17-36.html).  If you have this reader version (or any version starting with 2018), replace the server parameter from `acroviewR15` or `acroviewR17` to `acroviewR18` as shown below.  To access this dialogue box, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> in TeXnicCenter, select the "Latex => PDF" profile, then switch to the "Viewer" tab.

[image]

To check your reader version, open Adobe Acrobat Reader DC, under "Help" menu, click "About Adobe Acrobat Reader DC".  If the version number begins with

- 2018, set all your Server parameters to `acroviewR18`,
- 2017, set all your Server parameters to `acroviewR17`,
- 2015, set all your Server parameters to `acroviewR15`.

[Reference](https://forums.adobe.com/message/9460613#9460613) for all future versions of Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I am already affected by this.

Comment: I did all of the above (my version is 2018) nothing works yet. Same error :(

Comment: @HermanJaramillo Do you have Adobe **Acrobat** Reader DC? Or one without Acrobat

Comment: @FrenzyLi  Yes I do.

Comment: I ended up giving up on TexNicCenter in favor of TexWorks  which actually works quite well.

Comment: @HermanJaramillo Probably [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428892/texniccenter-does-not-work-with-adobe-anymore) is a solution. Perhaps somebody can tranfer the answer in some algorithm ;-)

Answer (score 5):

We're now in 2020, so the version is 20!

[image]

Comment: I edited the most-upvoted post with this new information.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after Adobe Reader update, solved with:

```
Executable path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe
Server = acroviewR15
Topic = control
```

defined in Build -> Define Output Profiles... -> choose "LateX to PDF" -> Viewer tab (for TeXnicCenter).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you supplement your answer with some information about *where* to type that code?

Comment: @egreg: How to open output as pdf directly? Should I need to make some changes in settings of my pdf reader? Right now, only the reader opens, not the document as pdf (which would be more convenient)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Reader Config]
If you use **Adobe Reader XI** version 11.0.23 (updated June 23, 2018), this trick will work: https://nw360.blogspot.com/2017/03/set-up-pdf-viewer-in-texniccenter.html

**View project's output** and  **Forward search**:
Choose **Command line argument** and type in **"%bm.pdf"**

**Close document** before running (La)TeX:
Select **DDE command** and the command is **[AppExit]**

**Server: arcroviewR11**
**Topic: Control**

The server above is for Adobe Reader.
For Adobe Acrobat Pro, use **arcroviewA11**.