# LateX -> PDF does no longer work in Adobe Reader DC 2017

Tags: pdftex

Yesterday, my Adobe Reader DC was updated to the 2017 version, and now LateX -> PDF does no longer work ('Cannot execute the command').
Is it possible that the DDE server has changed? Currently, I am using 'acroviewR15' as DDE server and I am using TeXnicCenter.

Comment: A quick google search gives this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/250472/117534. Have you tried the solutions from there?

Comment: Yes, this was working for me. But since the update of adobe it seems not to be working anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just spent an hour on this this morning.
You just have to change your server to acroviewR17 in the three boxes in the Viewer section of Definie Output Profiles (wherever you had acroviewR15).

It should work like a charm (it did for me).

Comment: Thanks! This works indeed, after restarting TeXnicCenter and chaning the server.