# TeXnic Center not interacting with Adobe Reader

Tags: pdf, texniccenter, adobe

Every time I do a pdf build, TeXnic center opens my Adobe Acrobat Reader DC (version 2019.010.20098), but does not actually open the document in the Reader; I have to do that manually from the File menu or from recently opened files. If my reader is already open, then TeXnic center does not build the file at all, but runs into a fatal error when I try to build. Worst of all, after each successful build, TeXnic center completely freezes for something like two full minutes, finally popping up an error message (see attached image).

[image: Error message from TeXnic center after each successful build: "Cannot execute the command"]

Here is a picture from my TeXnic Center settings that might also be helpful to see:

[image: Viewer profile settings]

This is extremely frustrating, and I would be grateful if anyone can help me troubleshoot this problem. If there is more information I need to provide, please just let me know. Thanks in advance for any help anyone is able to offer.

Comment: it is a well known feature of reader that it locks the file and prevents any program updating it, if you use more or less any other pdf viewer the issue will not occur.

Comment: Is there one you would recommend in particular? I once had an office mate in grad school who worked around that problem by having TeXnic center first issue a command to close the Adobe reader, and then reopen it, but I can't remember how she did it.

Comment: Either way, that issue is the smallest part of the problem. What really bothers me is having to wait 2 or 3 minutes after each build before I can do any more editing!

Comment: I can recommend SumatraPDF; it's free, fast and is working perfectly together with TeXnicCenter.

Comment: Well, maybe switching viewers will resolve the other problem, too. Does it get along with Windows 10?

Comment: there are some hints on closing the document in acrobat before running tex here, as for other viewers I don't know, personally I use xpdf but  that's not a native windows thing  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364613/1090

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have the same problem popping up occasionally after an update to the adobe reader. What helps sometimes is to update these [image]

To match the version of your adobe acrobat reader

Comment: Interesting. Is it just a matter of adding "R19", or do I need to worry about the full version number?

Comment: Holy cow, this worked! Thank you so much! :D :D :D

Comment: I have `Version 2019.010.20098` and the above works for me. Don't  ask me why, I'm using Windows+Adobe only on my work PC

Comment: Expect this to happen again in a few months :D

Comment: Next time, I'll know what to do! Thanks again.

Comment: Of course. So excited I almost forgot :)

Comment: can confirm that this in fact helps. upvoted and added to favorites...

Comment: NOTE AcroviewR19 is for "Reader versions" and after the 2020 update this year will become AcroviewR20 For those using a full version (3D standard Pro DC etc.) its now AcroviewA19 and of course will change to  AcroviewA20 during the course of this year