# latest updates to lua* break ... something

Tags: luatex, miktex, luaotfload

So, now, after most recent (23 Apr) updates (I'm using MiKTeX 2.9) to various things related to lualatex, I noticed that compilation of anything takes twice as long as it did (say) 10 minutes ago (i.e., before I applied the updates). Didn't take long to see why.

Basically, now, every time I try to compile something, it re-runs luaotfload.

> ```
> luaotfload | Updating the font names database:
> luaotfload | Scanning TEXMF and OS fonts..
> ```

Every time - it should only have to do this on c, but since the updates, it tries to do this every time, which is where the added time to compile comes from.

Compilation seems to progress 'correctly', but something that takes twice as long (because of what appears to be a bug causing luaotfload to run every time a file is compiled, is not an 'update'.

Wonder if its related to the following. If I bring up and admin cmd console, and run

`mkluatexfontdb -f -vvv`

I get an error:

> ```
> mklualatexdb: Windows API Error 5: Access is denied 
> mklualatexdb: Data: C://Documents and settings
> ```

When I run this on my other machines - which I have not 'updated' runs fine.

Suggestions?

Comment: Please take a look on [Windows API error 5: “Access is denied” when trying to compile TikZ picture](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51799/windows-api-error-5-access-is-denied-when-trying-to-compile-tikz-picture). It’s BTW a suspected duplicate.

Comment: One potential issue is that `mkluatexfontdb` adds the *current* directory to the search path. So you cannot execute the command in a directory that has special files that you cannot read, even as administrator. Try executing the command inside an empty directory instead.

Comment: Any news about the problem? If it has been solved with some system update, then, please, make it known.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem that doesn't seem reproducible