# mptopdf package for graphicx

Tags: graphics, pdftex, miktex

I'm writing up some mathematics notes in LaTeX using Texmaker, and want to include some diagrams (from image files).

When I include the graphicx package, I keep getting a pop-up entitled 'Package Installation', saying that 'tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii' is missing, and asking me to install mptopdf, whenever I compile the file to pdf.

If I click install, the pdf compiles and loads fine (at least it seems to), but it prompts me again to install the next time as well!

I could just uncheck the box about 'show this dialog', but I feel it might be better to address the issue properly. Any suggestions?

[image: Here's a screenshot of the pop-up]
[image: This error message appears briefly in the log (was hard to screenshot!)]

Here's my preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
```

One line where I want an image is

```
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{trianglesymettries.png}
```

But I get the pop-up even without this line. (It only stops if I remove '\usepackage{graphicx}'.)

I'm editing using Texmaker 4.0.4, with the MiKTeX 2.9 distribution on Windows 8.

Comment: Try if it works if you choose a specific repository instead of a random one. Or try to install mptopdf with the package manager.

Comment: It is also possible that you need to give yourself writing rights http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78674/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I gave myself writing rights as suggested and that seems to have let it install properly. Thank you!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it could be solved with a user right change.