# MiKTeX installation permission error

Tags: errors, miktex, installing, windows

I'm trying to install MiKTeX but I'm getting an error with `mfc100.dll permission denied`:

The operation could not be completed for the following reason:

```
Permission denied: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin/x64/mfc100.dll
```

I have a 64bit Windows 8.1 laptop.

Comment: Did you run installation as administrator?

Comment: Your firewall may also be blocking access to system-critical libraries.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/) This might be the same problem as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51799/windows-api-error-5-access-is-denied-when-trying-to-compile-tikz-picture; @sevenkul’s answer has worked for me several times. Please take a look at that as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: @doncherry Just a reminder that your duplicate suggestion worked for me (and others seemingly). Perhaps it is more suitable to close as duplicate than 'unclear what you asking'.

Comment: @StevenJeuris I agree, that might be more suitable. I think the idea was that the OP didn’t give sufficient information at the time, so we closed it as "unclear". I’m not sure if reopening and reclosing the question is worth the trouble though, at this point.

Answer (score 3):

Disable your anti-virus and firewall for a while and try to install the MikTeX again. I'd experienced similar problem before and this actually worked.

Comment: This worked for me!