# LaTeX compiling very slow when internet is connected

Tags: pdftex, miktex

LaTex compiler in my system taking unusual time to build pdf when connected to internet. But it is running normally when PC is not connected with internet. Mine is MiKTeX 2.9.5105, windows 32 bit version and Texmaker editor. My OS is Windows 8, 64 bit.

I kept Windows defender and firewall off. I tried uninstalling and re-installing of MiKTeX and Texmaker, tried using 64 bit one, uninstallation of unnecessary softwares in system etc. 
Task manager and resource monitor are not giving details of which process is making the slow compiling of LaTeX with internet connection.

I hope some of you can help me.

Added from comment:  But I need to use images.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{amssymb,array} 
\graphicspath{C:\Users\user\Desktop} 
\begin{document}
```

Comment: Close your chrome tabs, they eat memory like hell!

Comment: Thanks Yiannis. But unfortunately the case is the same even when all the chrome tabs are closed.

Comment: Run a minimal with the packages you use and post the log, for us to have a look.

Comment: If you use packages that are not installed yet, they are downloaded during compilation which is indeed a bit slow.

Comment: @Yiannis Script without figures is running fast. But I need to use images. \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb,array}
\graphicspath{C:\Users\user\Desktop}
\begin{document}

Comment: Thanks marczellm. A package installation notification always comes before compilation. How to install all packages 'not-on the fly'?

Comment: @KrishnaPrasad something is wrong then as it should only happen once (for each package) once it is installed it shouldn't fetch it again.

Comment: Thanks David. The package installation notifies'the required file tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii is missing. It is the part of the followimg package mptopdf'. This happens always just after quick build. Should I change the installation source? How to update the MiKTeX with all packages?

Comment: @KrishnaPrasad I would suggest trying what [sevenkul wrote in his answer to another thread](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78674/11002)

Comment: Also, your `\graphicspath` is certainly wrong, please read the manual of `graphicx` for full instructions on how to use it. I don't think you need this instruction, you can simply move your graphics to the folder where your `.tex` file is.

Comment: Thanks yo'. I have tried the procedure as in sevenkul's answer. And I added figure without using\graphicspath, \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Hi world!
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{image}
\end{figure}
\end{document}. But it is still very slow!

Comment: Thanks Kurt. The installed one is MikTeX 2.9.5105 basic tex/latex system with the user account. How to compile latex from the windows terminal? I have uninstalled the basic MikTeX, and trying to install the complete tex/latex system version 2.9.4503, 64 bit.

Comment: Thank you friends. Thank you Kurt.:) I installed the complete version of MiKTeX 2.9.4503, 64 bit and it is successfully working in good speed, when connected with internet also.!!