# "Windows api error 5" when trying to install MikTex

Tags: errors, miktex, windows

I tried to install basic-miktex-2.9.5105 (system: Windows 7), but always got the error message "Windows API error 5: Access denied    info: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin\initexmf.exe".

I tried the answers given in the post [Windows API error 5: "Access is denied" when trying to compile TikZ picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51799/windows-api-error-5-access-is-denied-when-trying-to-compile-tikz-picture)
but none of them really worked:
Giving permissions to read and write in the MiKTeX 2.9 folder did not help, neither did granting the administrator full rights to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.pdf. And it didn't make any difference whether I installed MikTex into "Program Files" or not. I do not have Adobe Reader installed on my system (but PDFXChange Viewer). The TMP/TEMP files are located on C:, I ran the installation file as "administrator" and I moved the installation file to another folder - none of these helped.

FYI please find the logfile below (the logfile says "Microsoft Windows Vista Business Edition" and not "Windows 7" because the initial problem I had with the installation was an "API error 2". This  error could be solved by setting the MiKTeX installer to Compatibilty Mode Vista; cf. https://superuser.com/questions/489234/windows-api-error-2-when-installing-miktex-win7)

Do you have any ideas?

```
MiKTeX Setup 2.9.4503 Report

Date: Sunday, February 08, 2015
Time: 00:43:55
OS version: Microsoft Windows Vista Business Edition, 32-bit (build 6000)
SystemAdmin: yes
PowerUser: false
SharedSetup: yes
Setup path: C:\basic-miktex-2.9.5105.exe
UserRoots: <none specified>
UserData: <none specified>
UserConfig: <none specified>
CommonRoots: <none specified>
CommonData: <none specified>
CommonConfig: <none specified>

Installation: C:\MiKTeX 2.9
Loading package database...
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: "C:\MiKTeX 2.9"
package repository: C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Temp\mik56558
visiting repository C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Temp\mik56558...
repository type: local package repository
loading lightweight database...
lightweight database digest: 2e1ee451b3ebfd4ef4afc81bbceafc9f
going to install 9562 file(s) (161 package(s))
problem: C:\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin\MiKTeX209-core-PS.dll does not exist
problem: C:\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin\MiKTeX209-core.dll does not exist
problem: C:\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin\MiKTeX209-packagemanager-PS.dll does not exist
problem: C:\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin\MiKTeX209-packagemanager.dll does not exist
extracting files from ae.tar.lzma...
extracting files from amscls.tar.lzma...
extracting files from amsfonts.tar.lzma...
extracting files from amsmath.tar.lzma...
extracting files from avantgar.cab...
extracting files from babel.tar.lzma...
extracting files from bidi.tar.lzma...
extracting files from bookman.cab...
extracting files from carlisle.tar.lzma...
extracting files from cbcoptic.tar.lzma...
extracting files from cm.tar.lzma...
extracting files from courier.tar.lzma...
extracting files from dehyph-exptl.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ec.tar.lzma...
extracting files from elhyphen.tar.lzma...
extracting files from enctex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from euenc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from eurosym.tar.lzma...
extracting files from float.cab...
extracting files from fontspec.tar.lzma...
extracting files from geometry.tar.lzma...
extracting files from graphics.tar.lzma...
extracting files from helvetic.cab...
extracting files from hoekwater.tar.lzma...
extracting files from hyperref.tar.lzma...
extracting files from hyph-utf8.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ifxetex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from jknappen.cab...
extracting files from latex-fonts.tar.lzma...
extracting files from latex2e-help-texinfo.tar.lzma...
extracting files from lm.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ltxbase.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ltxmisc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from lua-alt-getopt.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luainputenc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from lualibs.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luamplib.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luaotfload.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luatexbase.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luatextra.tar.lzma...
extracting files from mflogo.cab...
extracting files from miktex-arctrl-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-biber-bin.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-bibtex-base.cab...
extracting files from miktex-bibtex-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-bibtex8bit-base.cab...
extracting files from miktex-bibtex8bit-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-cairo-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-cjkutils-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-config-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-cweb-base.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-cweb-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dict-english.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dict-french.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dict-german.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-doc-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvicopy-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvipdfm-base-2.7.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvipdfmx-base-2.7.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvipdfmx-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvipng-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvips-base.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvips-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvips-doc.cab...
extracting files from miktex-etex-base-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-findtexmf-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-fontconfig-base.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-fontconfig-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-fontname-base.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-fonts-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-freetype-base.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-freetype-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-freetype2-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-ghostscript-base-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-ghostscript-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-graphics-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-graphite2-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-gsf2pk-base.cab...
extracting files from miktex-gsf2pk-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-hunspell-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-hyph-french.tar.bz2...
extracting files from miktex-hyph-german.tar.bz2...
extracting files from miktex-hyph-usenglish.cab...
extracting files from miktex-icu-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-kpathsea-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-latex-config-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-lua52-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-luatex-base.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-luatex-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-makeindex-base.cab...
extracting files from miktex-makeindex-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-metafont-base.cab...
extracting files from miktex-metafont-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-metafont-misc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-metapost-base-2.7.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-metapost-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mft-base.cab...
extracting files from miktex-mfware-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-misc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mkfntmap-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mktex-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mo-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mpm-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mthelp-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mtprint-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mtx-bin.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-omega-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-pdftex-base-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-pdftex-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-pdftex-doc-2.6.tar.bz2...
extracting files from miktex-pmx-bin.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-poppler-base.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-poppler-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-ps2pk-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-psutils-base.cab...
extracting files from miktex-psutils-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-qt4-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-runtime-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-teckit-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex-base.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex-misc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex4ht-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-texify-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-texinfo-base.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-texinfo-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-texware-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-texworks-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-texworks-doc-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-vc100-bin.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-web-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-xdvipdfmx-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-xetex-base.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-xetex-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-yap-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-zip-bin.tar.lzma...
extracting files from multirow.cab...
extracting files from ncntrsbk.cab...
extracting files from oberdiek.tar.lzma...
extracting files from palatino.cab...
extracting files from pdftex-def.tar.lzma...
extracting files from pslatex.cab...
extracting files from psnfss.cab...
extracting files from pstricks.tar.lzma...
extracting files from rsfs.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ruhyphen.cab...
extracting files from tds.cab...
extracting files from thumbpdf.tar.lzma...
extracting files from times.cab...
extracting files from tools.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ukrhyph.cab...
extracting files from utopia.cab...
extracting files from xetexref.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xgreek.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xkeyval.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xltxtra.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xunicode.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xypic.tar.lzma...
extracting files from zapfchan.cab...
extracting files from zapfding.cab...
updating package definition directory ("C:\MiKTeX 2.9\tpm\packages")...
installed 2555 package definition files
visiting repository C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Temp\mik56558...
repository type: local package repository
loading lightweight database...
"C:\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin\initexmf.exe" --common-install="C:\MiKTeX 2.9" --rmfndb --admin --log-file="C:\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\config\uninst.log" --verbose:

An error occurred:
  source file: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\win\winProcess.cpp
  source line: 366
  message: Windows API error 5: Zugriff verweigert

  info: C:\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin\initexmf.exe
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I'm not a MikTeX user (I'm on linux) but I hope someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Perhaps a problem with a firewall on your system?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Another suggestion: run the installer from the command line with administrator privileges.

Answer (score 0):

I deactivated both my firewall and my antivirus programm before running the installer, so those weren't the problem.

I once more tried the solutions that are suggested in [Windows API error 5: "Access is denied" when trying to compile TikZ picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51799/windows-api-error-5-access-is-denied-when-trying-to-compile-tikz-picture)
and, finally, a slightly modified version of the suggestion given by sevenkul(15) did the trick:

"*If that is not enough, click Advanced button on the Security Tab. A window named Advanced Security Settings for Folder Name pops up. Then click Auditing Tab > Continue Button > Add Button. Type Users under "Enter the object names to select" and click OK.*"

In my case, a new window opened after clicking "OK". In this window, all the boxes below "success" have to be ticked - and the installation works.